# how do I set up my Server on Digital ocean

Tags: laravel-5, server, digital-ocean

I dont have much experience in server programming.

I want to move my site or setup a new site on digital Ocean. I can get as far as creating the droplet. Is there somewhere I can find a guide or some that can give a step by step of how to setup a Cpanel or something similar?

Comment: So you samt to setup Laravel project or Multiple Laravel projects on same droplet on Digital Ocean, I am doing this often let me know so I can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this video series from CodeCourse: [Digital ocean set up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-ok9d_6xrc&list=PLfdtiltiRHWGm8EAUXl2oBk5zjuvOTxsy)

This will give you a good guide on how to set up a basic droplet and how to secure it over sftp

From series: We'll be building a cloud server with Apache, PHP and MySQL, along with looking at accessing it with SFTP (SSH FTP) and protecting the server by using key access.